# How to scroll to top of iFrame from inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a single `iframe`, loaded into the page of same origin. This `iframe` has two `div`s that are visible one or another. With a click of button the currently active `div` is hidden and another `div` is made visible. This is working.

The problem is, after clicking on the `button`, the next `div` is visible but the buttom of the div is on the screen. I wanted to scroll to top of the `div` when it is made visible.

Code I tried:
**Snippet 1**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  // other code to handle visibility
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

*Works on the Page itself, but not when embedded as an iframe inside other pages.*

**Snippet 2**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  // other code to handle visibility
  window.parent.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

*Takes to the Top of parent Page*

How can I modify this code to take me to the top of iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.

Here's the code that worked.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  // other code to handle visibility
  $('.step2')[0].scrollIntoView();
  // step2 is the class name of the second div 
  // that is to be visible
}
```